# putting CLASSES back in array as3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I suppose I need to be able to get the name of the class an object belongs to.

1: I have two classes

```
CandyBar
BottledWater
```

2: I put their names in two arrays

```
var foodArray(CandyBar, BottledWater);
var waterArray();
```

3: I add children to stage using the array; like this

```
var foodItem = new foodArray[i];
```

4: I later try and move the reference for BottledWater to the waterArray, but can't. I'm not creating any new object or anything, just moving the reference from one array to another. Furthermore, I cant remove the reference either.

I suppose I could say I am adding children from an array, then wanting to push a reference to that "class" into another array, while removing the reference from the original array.

Comment: Are you trying to do `waterArray.push(foodItem)`?

Comment: `var foodItem = new foodArray[i];` is not adding the child to the stage at all. It is just creating an instance of the object.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to make an Array variable is:

```
var foodArray: Array = [CandyBar, BottledWater];
var waterArray: Array = new Array();
```

than you can do

```
waterArray.push( new foodArray[0] );
```

or

```
var foodItem = new foodArray[i]();
```

Comment: Should really be `new foodArray[i]()`